# Checking for special characters in string (in C)

Tags: c

Why does every word go into the if statement checking whether the string ends with a ',' and the one checking whether it ends with a '"'.

I see words like:

```
"held"
"hand"
"bond"
"like"
"was"
"her"
"familliar"
```

(all of the above is just examples of words that enters the if statements

```
void RemoveOddSigns(char *word){

    if(word[0] == '"'){
        strncpy(word, word + 1, strlen(word));
    }

    if(word[strlen(word - 1)] == '"'){
        word[strlen(word) - 1] == '\0';
    }

    if((word[strlen(word - 1)] == ',')){
        word[strlen(word) - 1] == '\0';
    }
```

Does anyone have any clue why such words think their ending is a `"` or a `,`?

Comment: You technically have undefined behaviour with `strncpy(word, word + 1, strlen(word));` — the source and target arrays are not allowed to overlap.  Use `memmove()` — that does allow overlapping copies — but you'll need to know how long the string is and remember to copy the null byte so the output is a string too.

Comment: Actually, there is no problem with that part of the code, that workd perfect, it is the two other if-statements that every word seems to enter

Comment: @LasseHarde Just because something seems to work does not make it well defined.  It may not be the source of your troubles in this question, but you should endeavor to fix any undefined behavior in your program lest you be unexpectedly accosted by nasal demons.

Comment: Actually, there is a problem with the `strncpy()` part of the code — the behaviour is undefined.  However, one of the possible results of undefined behaviour is the behaviour you hoped for; it is not required that things go awry, but they can go awry.

Comment: You are right, i will look straight into that! Thank you gentlemen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look hard at the parentheses in these two lines:

```
if((word[strlen(word - 1)] == ',')){
    word[strlen(word) - 1] == '\0';
}
           Here    ^   ^
```

The asymmetry is wrong.  Starting your search before the word starts is undefined behaviour.  I think the second line is more nearly correct, but you need to replace the `==` with `=` to assign the new value (as pointed out by [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53772230/checking-for-special-charecters-in-string-in-c/53772291#comment94396371_53772291)).  This problem also affects the previous paragraph of code.

```
if (word[strlen(word) - 1] == ',')
    word[strlen(word) - 1] = '\0';
```

Also, you technically have undefined behaviour with `strncpy(word, word + 1, strlen(word));` — the source and target arrays are not allowed to overlap (the formal prototype for `strncpy()` is [`char *strcat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.4), where the `restrict` means 'no overlap between `s1` and `s2`).  Use `memmove()` — that does allow overlapping copies — but you'll need to know how long the string is and remember to copy the null byte so the output is a string too.

Comment: Good catch, J. To complete your answer, you may as well also mention the use of `==` where `=` was intended (in the assignment).

Comment: Thank you comrades, you seem to have fixed thoose sneaky problems